Internet speed is less on Android version 14 in Xamarin android app
While working on Xamarin android app I observed that the app is getting very low internet speed, specifically on android version 14 using mobile data bit working fine using WIFI. While the other apps are working fine. This same app is working fine on android 13 and bellow versions using mobile data.
We tried updating the
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
